# Mic problem with Discord

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

well i have this problem with discord, i recently started using Ubuntu (18.04.4) and whether i'm in discordapp or in a discord tab on internet, my mic goes static, being unable to hear my voice, only static sound. Could anyone help me? 
PD: in win10 my mic works perfecly, also i have to say my mic is an internal mic on my laptop.

Comment: I think Discord may be doing weird things, occasionally when I open the web app while playing audio/video all sound goes to static until I close the tab. But then if I open it again it's fine....